# Checking if JSON request is different from previous request (data has been updated) in python

Tags: python, json, request

I'm reading data from a json file using requests.. and wish to store those values in an excel file. The issue I'm running into is I don't know the interval at which this json file is being updated, so it's hard to make my scheduler perfect.. I end up with duplicate values. I can't seem to find any libraries that could check for me.

In this scenario, I end up with a duplicate at 1:10 and wish to not add it since it is the same as the one at 1:05. In some instances, there may be more than one duplicate at a time and I wish to check this before it evens gets added rather than added and then deleted.

Is there a simpler way to approach this problem?

Example:

```
timestamp   stock  buy  sell 
   1:05       1     10    10
   1:10       1     10    10
   1:15       1     20    16

def do_this():
    previous_data = []
    try:
        response = requests.get(JSON_LINK)
        previous_data = response.content
    except Exception:
        print('Failed in main')


    if(previous_data == response.content):
        print('same data')
    else:
        print('new data')
```

I realized this isn't going to work at previous_data = [] will always end up taking in whatever the current response is, not the previous response data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try searching the existing data for the same record you have. If the record exists then its an update, if not its a delete.

You could also cache the previous request. When a new request comes in, compare it to the cache and remove duplicates. This approach only works if you care about previous and next requests.

"I don't know the interval at which this json file is being updated" - you can add a custom header to requests with the time the request was store this time as 'latest'. When another request comes in, check the header time value, if its older than latest, throw it away.

Comment: Haven't looked into cache, but I will now! Looks like a solid approach if I can figure it out. But yes, I'm only looking for previous and next requests.. Not necessarily looking throughout the entire excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that JSON can have the same values at different times.
There are mostly two way to check for equality of objects- one is by char to char checking and other is by matching the hash values.

So, one approach will be to create a HashSet. Whenever a new response comes you compute the hash and check if this hash exists or not. If exists, then simply discard the response, if it doesn't exist you store the hash value in the hashSet and response value in your excel.
**NOTE: Hash matching consumes less time than string matching.**

Comment: I'll try this approach! Thanks.